# Vertcat error in matlab

Tags: matlab

When I run a code it shows error using vertcat in the marked line. What does it mean and how to change it?

```
f = [-10 -20 -40 -10 -10 80 70 90];  
A = [ 1 1 2 1 3 0 0 0 -----> vertcat error
      2 1 3 2 2 0 0 0 
      1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0
     -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
      0-1 0 0 0 1 1 1
      0 0-1 0 0 1 0 0 
      0 0 0-1 0 0 1 0
      0 0 0 0-1 0 0 1];

b  = [800 600 900 0 0 0 0 0]; 
ub = [inf inf inf inf inf 90 57 93]; 
lb = zeros(8,1); 
[x fval]=linprog(-f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub);
```

Comment: What is the code you are trying to run?

Comment: The typical error in `vertcat` is that the argument list doesn't have the same number of columns. However, without some background information on what you are doing it is difficult to understand the source or error. Add your code, or some standalone part that will cause this error.

Comment: %lowerbound
lb=zeros(8,1);

%upperbound
ub=inf(8,1);
ub(6)=90;
ub(7)=57;
ub(8)=93;

f=[-10 -20 -40 -10 -10 80 70 90];

A = [ 1 1 2 1 3 0 0 0; 
     2 1 3 2 2 0 0 0 ;
     1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0;
    -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ;
     0-1 0 0 0 1 1 1;
     0 0-1 0 0 1 0 0 ;
     0 0 0-1 0 0 1 0;
     0 0 0 0-1 0 0 1];

b=[800 600 900 0 0 0 0 0];

ub=[inf inf inf inf inf 90 57 93];

[x fval]=linprog(-f,A,b,[],[],lb,ub);

Answer (score 1):

`A` was missing some spaces. This should work:

```
A = [ 1 1 2 1 3 0 0 0;
      2 1 3 2 2 0 0 0;
      1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0;
      -1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1;
      0 -1 0 0 0 1 1 1;
      0 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0;
      0 0 0 -1 0 0 1 0;
      0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 1]

A =

     1     1     2     1     3     0     0     0
     2     1     3     2     2     0     0     0
     1     2     1     1     0     0     0     0
    -1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0    -1     0     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0    -1     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0    -1     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0    -1     0     0     1
```

Comment: Just adding a bit of clarity: `0-1` is considered as `0-1=-1`, i.e. one element.
The solutions to these kind of problems is either to be verbose and add `,` everywhere or pay attention to the spacing.

Comment: Speaking of which I wish MATLAB's errors were more precise. E.g. in this case it could try to display which row causes the issue.

Comment: Yes, it's a known limitation. Getting closer to a solution is using F5 (which forces to save the file), but at least returns the first line of the block of commands that generated the error.